# UIPageViewController does not allow uitextfield to be selected

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am hitting a really interesting problem with UIPageViewController. If you click on a UITextfield inside of one of the pages, the page will flash and then disappear.

This only seems to happen when the transition style is set to

`UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`

The easiest way to duplicate the problem is to create a new Page View based project, change the transition style, add a `UITextField` to the storyboard. Scroll a few pages and then click on the `UITextField`, that page will disappear. This only happens the first time you run the app, so you need to restart to duplicate the issue.

I don't know what's wrong, but does anyone know a work around?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, but interestingly, only with a UITextView. UITextFields seem to work fine. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612240/cannot-impliment-uitextview-inside-a-uipageviewcontroller

I've provided an example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246444/unexpected-uipageviewcontroller-behaviour/18307344#18307344