# Cannot Impliment UITextview inside a UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I have a strange issue , I have a page app in which one page I had used a `UITextView`, but when I tap on the `UITextView` it moves to the next page, can't write anything on it.

There is no issue when I use `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`. The only issue is with `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`. Anyone know the solution? please help me

Comment: How could you tap on UITextView inside a UIPageVIewController? The UIPageViewController absorbs the tabs.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same issue myself, and it appears that it's a consequence of some default behavior that occurs whenever a *UITextField* or *UITextView* becomes first responder inside a *UIScrollView*.

**The solution to prevent your *UITextView* from scrolling the *UIPageViewController* is to first embed it into a *UIScrollView* instead of directly into a page's main view.**

This works because when the *UITextView* becomes first responder it will search for the earliest superview in the view hierarchy that is of type *UIScrollView*, and it will scroll that scrollview to accommodate for the keyboard covering the screen. If you don't wrap the *UITextView* inside a *UIScrollView*, your *UIPageViewController*'s internal *UIScrollView* will be chosen and scrolled, producing undesired behavior.

Comment: Dude!  I only regret that I have but one upvote to give for your wisdom.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer the link below..

UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html